# Install SSL Certificate for Electron Application

Tags: 16.04, ssl, electron

I'm currently building a debian installation package to deploy a electron application to our internal linux desktop machines (Ubuntu 16.04).

The app contacts an internal server that uses certificates signed by our internal CA. This certificates are not accepted.

I can start the application with the option `--ignore-certificate-errors`, but this just a workaround during testing.

Where do I have to import the CA certificates to allow the electron application to communicate with our server?

They are already added using `update-ca-certificates`, so there seems to be something else.

Any ideas?

Ralf

Answer (score 1):

Calling the [app.importCertificate](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appimportcertificateoptions-callback-linux) API providing the certificate in pkcs12 format does the trick.